# I am using Oracle SQL Developer and want to extract the days of the week from timestamps. Am I on the right track with the syntax?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
SELECT DAYOFWEEK(TIMESTAMP('07-JUN-21 12.00.00.0000000 AM'))
```

--or

```
SELECT
     EXTRACT (DAYOFWEEK
     FROM
     {'07-JUN-21 12.00.00.0000000}) as dayofweek,
FROM table_name
```

Comment: there is no DAYOFWEEK function in oracle

Comment: The only right track is [Datetime Functions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Single-Row-Functions.html#GUID-5652DBC2-41C7-4F07-BEDD-DAF620E35F3C) in SQL Language Reference. Also check section Datetime literals for correct syntax of timestamp and date literals

Answer (score 2):

I think you are better off using `TO_CHAR`:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'DAY')
FROM DUAL;
```

If you don't want the full day name, you can use `DY` or another format model.  All of which are listed in the Oracle Documentation [Link](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-49B32A81-0904-433E-B7FE-51606672183A)

Comment: In MySQL `DAYOFWEEK()` returns the index of the day in the week. So the the format make the Seeker needs is probably`'D'`.